# regular expression for username that allow number or characters and some special characters

Tags: regex

I have following regular expression to verify username

```
strUsername.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_.@]{6,100}$/g)
```

User name must be minimum 6 and maximum length of 100 number or characters and following special characters _.@ are optional.

It works for most cases, but somehow this username user-omega32 get passed, which is really should not be. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both anchors `^ and $` (i.e. line start and line end)

```
strUsername.match(/^[\w.@]{6,100}$/)
```

Also `\w` can be used in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: I tried strUsername.match(/^[\w_.@]{6,100}$/g)) and it worked. But I don't understand, why do I need add ^? Why \w is the same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]? And do you know /g means?

Comment: Problem is that for the input of `user-omega32` your regex matches `omega32` (since you don't have `^` anchor). `/g` is for global and since you're matching single value you don't need it. Finally `\w is shortcut for [a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Thank you very much. So I don't need /g?

Comment: Also, should I always start with ^ and end with $ when I writing a regex?

Comment: That depends on what exactly the requirement is but in most of the cases you should use `^ and $`